# Is possible use a foreach loop of Perl to process different files with R?

Tags: regex, r, perl, foreach, statistics

im tried to process different files like an input to R script, for this I use a foreach loop in Perl, but R send me a warning:

```
Problem while running this R command:
a <- read.table(file="~/Desktop/ncRNA/Data/Inputs/Boxplot_all/All/$newquery")

Error:
file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
Calls: read.table -> file
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
cannot open file '/Users/cristianarleyvelandiahuerto/Desktop/ncRNA/Data/Inputs/Boxplot_all/All/$newquery': No such file or directory
Execution halted
```

My code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Statistics::R;
use Data::Dumper;

my $R = Statistics::R->new();

my @query = (
    '~/Desktop/ncRNA/Data/Inputs/Boxplot_all/All/dvex_all_rRNA_ce.RF00001.txt',
    '~/Desktop/ncRNA/Data/Inputs/Boxplot_all/All/dvex_all_rRNA_ce_60.RF00001.txt',
    '~/Desktop/ncRNA/Data/Inputs/Boxplot_all/All/dvex_all_rRNA_ce_70.RF00001.txt',
    '~/Desktop/ncRNA/Data/Inputs/Boxplot_all/All/dvex_all_rRNA_ce_80.RF00001.txt',
    '~/Desktop/ncRNA/Data/Inputs/Boxplot_all/All/dvex_all_rRNA_ce_90.RF00001.txt'
);

foreach my $query(@query) {
    my $newquery = $query;
    $newquery =~ s/(.*)\/(dvex_all.*)(\.txt)/$2$3/g;
    print "$newquery\n";
    $R->run(q`a <- read.table(file="~/Desktop/ncRNA/Data/Inputs/Boxplot_all/All/$newquery")`);
    $R->run(q`res <- summary(a$V2)`);
    my $output_value = $R->get('res');
    print "Statistical Summary = $output_value\n";
}
```

With regex I changed the name of the input, but R don't recognizes this like as file. Can I do that? Some suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have:

```
$R->run(q`...`);
```

i.e., you're using the [`q` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators). String interpolation is not done with `q`. The immediate solution is to use

```
 $R->run(qq`...`);
```

Comment: Simple and effective solution. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

You used Perl's quote operator `q()`, which has the same semantics as a single quoted string — that is, no variable interpolation. If you don't want to use a double quoted string (or the equivalent `qq()` operator), then you have to concatenate the variable into your query:

```
use feature 'say';
my $workdir = "~/Desktop/ncRNA/Data/Inputs/Boxplot_all/All/";
for my $query (@query) {  
  (my $newquery = $query) =~ s{\A.*/(?=dvex_all.*[.]txt\z)}{};
  say $newquery;
  # actually, here you should escape any <"> double quotes in $workdir and $newquery.
  $R->run(q#a <- read.table(file="# . $workdir . $newquery . q#")#);
  $R->run(q#res <- summary(a$V2)#);
  my $output_value = $R->get('res');
  say "Statistical Summary = $output_value";
}
```

Other improvements I made:

- proper intendation is the first step to correct code
- The `say` function is more comfortable than `print`.
- The substitution has a better delimiter, and now cleary shows what it does: Deleting the path from the filename. Actually, we should be using one of the cross-platform modules that do this.
- I used the substitute in copy idiom `(my $copy = $orig) =~ s///`. In perl5 v16, you can use the `/r` flag instead: `my $copy = $orig =~ s///r`.
- The `/g` flag for the regex is useless.
- I anchored the match at the start and end of the string.
- The ``` q`` ``` strings now have a more visible delimiter

Answer (score 0):

I don't know r. but it looks like you should concatenate your string.

$R->run(q`a <- read.table(file="~/Desktop/ncRNA/Data/Inputs/Boxplot_all/All/".$newquery)`);

Answer (score 0):

R will not concatenate a string using a "$" operator. That "$query" is inside an R function argument so you cannot rely on Perl-operators. (Caveat: I'm not a Perl-user, so I'm making an assumption that your code is creating an R object within the loop named 'query') If I'm right then you may need to use paste0():

The file argument might look like:

```
 file=paste0("~/Desktop/ncRNA/Data/Inputs/Boxplot_all/All/", query)
```